# How can I split a list of tuples scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, tuples, higher-order-functions

I have this list in Scala (which in reality has length 500):

```
List((1,List(1,2,3)), (2,List(1,2,3)), (3, List(1,2,3)))
```

What could I do so that I can make a new list which contains the following:

```
List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3))
```

Basically I wanna have a new list of tuples which will contain the first element of the old tuple and each element of the list inside the tuple. I am not sure how to start implementing this and this is why I have posted no code to show my attempt. I am really sorry, but I cant grasp this. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val xs = List((1,List(1,2,3)), (2,List(1,2,3)), (3, List(1,2,3)))
xs: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((1,List(1, 2, 3)), (2,List(1, 2, 3)), (3,List(1, 2, 3)))

scala> xs.flatMap { case (x, ys) => ys.map(y => (x, y)) }
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3))
```

Comment: @hispaniccoder Here are online tutorials for Scala, FP and popular Scala libraries: https://www.scala-exercises.org

Answer (score 4):

Exactly the same as @Andriy but using a [**for comprehension**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html). 
Which in the end is exactly the [same](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) but is more readable IMHO.

```
val result = for {
  (x, ys) <- xs
  y <- ys
} yield (x, y) // You can also use x -> y
```

*(Again, I would recommend you to follow any tutorial, this is a basic exercise which if you had understand how `map` & `flatMap` works you shouldn't have any problem)*

Comment: Yeah you are right! I feel like most examples though show easier exercises than this one, this is why I am a bit confused when needing to implement something more demanding. Thanks for the clarification, its been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth mentioning that the solution by Andriy Plokhotnyuk can also be re-written as a for-comprehension:

```
val list = List((1,List(1,2,3)), (2,List(1,2,3)), (3, List(1,2,3)))

val pairs = for {
  (n, nestedList) <- list
  m <- nestedList
} yield (n, m)

assert(pairs == List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)))
```

The compiler will effectively re-write the for-comprehension to a `flatMap`/`map` chain as described in another answer.